# Roblox: StartCharacterScript seems to be overriding ServerScriptService problem

Tags: lua, roblox, conflict

I have two scripts a Chopping (AxeServer) Script and an Grab script the Chopping Script is located is ServerScriptService and the Grab (Dragger) Script is located in StarCharacterScript. But when Dragger is enabled the chopping no longer works, If i disable it then the AxeServer script works fine.

Below are my two scripts. (I'm not great at scripting but i've watched lot's of videos and I am starting to understand).
Dragger

```
local CAS = game:GetService("ContextActionService")

local GrabObject = nil
local GrabStart = false
local Dragger = nil

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

local DraggerEnabled = true

function Grab(actionName, UserInputState, InputObject)
    if not DraggerEnabled then
        return
    end

    if actionName == "Grab" then
        if UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then
            local Magnitude = (mouse.Hit.Position - character.Head.CFrame.Position).magnitude
            if Magnitude < 10 then
                if mouse.Target then
                    GrabObject = mouse.Target
                    GrabStart = true

                    local DragBall = createDragBall()
                    DragBall.CFrame = mouse.Hit
                    Dragger = DragBall   

                    mouse.TargetFilter = GrabObject
                    local DragBallWeld = weldBetween(DragBall, GrabObject)
                    addMover(DragBall)

                    while Dragger do
                        local cf = CFrame.new(character.Head.Position, mouse.Hit.Position)
                        Dragger.Mover.Position = (cf + (cf.LookVector * 10)).Position
                        Dragger.RotMover.CFrame = camera.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(Dragger.RotOffset.Value.X, Dragger.RotOffset.Value.Y, Dragger.RotOffset.Value.Z)
                        wait()
                    end
                    mouse.TargetFilter = nil
                end
            end       
        elseif UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.End then
            GrabObject = nil
            GrabStart = false
            if Dragger then
                Dragger:Destroy()
                Dragger = nil
            end

        end
    end
end

function weldBetween(a, b)
    local weld = Instance.new("ManualWeld", a)
    weld.C0 = a.CFrame:inverse() * b.CFrame
    weld.Part0 = a
    weld.Part1 = b
    return weld   
end

function addMover(part)
    local newMover = Instance.new("BodyPosition") --depreciated to what?
    newMover.Parent = part
    newMover.MaxForce = Vector3.new(4000, 4000, 4000)
    newMover.P = 4000
    newMover.D = 1000
    newMover.Position = part.Position
    newMover.Name = "Mover"

    local newRot = Instance.new("BodyGyro") -- depreciated to what?
    newRot.Parent = part
    newRot.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(3000, 3000, 3000)
    newRot.P = 3000
    newRot.D = 1000
    newRot.CFrame = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame
    newRot.Name = "RotMover"

    local RotOffset = Instance.new("CFrameValue")
    RotOffset.Name = "RotOffset"
    RotOffset.Parent = part
end

function createDragBall()
    local DragBall = Instance.new("Part") --change to log maybe
    DragBall.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Electric blue")
    DragBall.Material = Enum.Material.Wood
    DragBall.Size = Vector3.new(.2, .2, .2)    -- change this for the sizing of an object
    DragBall.Shape = "Ball"
    DragBall.Name = "DragBall"
    DragBall.Parent = workspace
    return DragBall
end

CAS:BindAction("Grab", Grab, false, Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1)
```

Here is my Axe Server script.

```
local re = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("AxeRE")

local cooldown = {}

re.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, target, mouseHit)
    if not cooldown[player] and player.Character and target and target.Name == "Trunk" and target:FindFirstChild("Health") and mouseHit then

        local hrp = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart
        local distance = (hrp.Position - target.Position).Magnitude

        if distance <= 6 then
            cooldown[player] = true

            if not target:FindFirstChild("MaxHealth") then
                local maxHealth = Instance.new("IntValue")
                maxHealth.Name = "MaxHealth"
                maxHealth.Value = target.Health.Value
                maxHealth.Parent = target
            end

            target.Health.Value -= 1

            if target.Health.Value < 1 then
                local treeBottom = target.CFrame:ToWorldSpace(CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0, -target.Size.Y/2, 0)))
                local treeTop = target.CFrame:ToWorldSpace(CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0, target.Size.Y/2, 0)))

                local yHeight = target.CFrame:PointToObjectSpace(mouseHit.Position).Y + target.Size.Y/2

                local treeMiddle = treeBottom:PointToWorldSpace(Vector3.new(0, yHeight, 0))

                local bottomSize = (treeMiddle - treeBottom.Position).Magnitude
                local topSize = (treeMiddle - treeTop.Position).Magnitude

                local bottomPos = treeBottom:PointToWorldSpace(Vector3.new(0, bottomSize/2, 0))
                local topPos = treeTop:PointToWorldSpace(Vector3.new(0, -topSize/2, 0))

                target.Health:Destroy()

                local bottomPart = target:Clone()
                bottomPart.Position = bottomPos
                bottomPart.Size = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
                bottomPart.Parent = workspace

                local topPart = target:Clone()
                topPart.Position = topPos
                topPart.Name = "Log"
                topPart.Size = Vector3.new(2, 20, 2)
                topPart.Anchored = false
                topPart.Parent = workspace

                local bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
                bv.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
                bv.Velocity = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame.LookVector
                bv.Parent = topPart
                game:GetService("Debris"):AddItem(bv, 1)

                local newHealthValue = target.MaxHealth:Clone()
                newHealthValue.Name = "Health"
                newHealthValue.Parent = bottomPart
                newHealthValue:Clone().Parent = topPart

                if target.Parent:FindFirstChild("Leaves") then
                    local leaves = target.Parent.Leaves
                    spawn(function()
                        leaves.CanCollide = false
                        leaves.Anchored = false
                        wait(1)
                        leaves.Parent:Destroy()
                    end)
                end

                target:Destroy()
            end

            wait(1)
            cooldown[player] = false
        end
    end
end
```

Any help on stopping these two stopping each other would be great.  Basically when a tool is equiped it fires the axe script then when its put back in the backup the dragger script is enabled.

Many Thanks

Alex

Comment: Could anyone help?